# Can I change Apache2 config file name?

Tags: apache, rename

I have a production (ubuntu 16) server with multiple websites. In `/etc/apache2/site-enabled`, I have all my config files. some files have been created with the wrong names. How can I rename safely file in a production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename the file, apache doesn't depend on the file name, it just picks up all configuration files in that directory.